# React componentDidMount and working with Promises?

Tags: reactjs, post, promise, es6-promise

Getting really fed up now! I am trying to get a Spinner element to appear while 3 functions run in the componentDidMount function.

From what I gather the render comes before componentDidMount, so I am running the Spinner in the render, while:

1. a cookie value is retrieved from this.getValidToken()
2. then an axios post request sets state of isLoggedin (using above value as payload)
3. then the logic() function runs a simple if statement to either log user in or redirect to 
   error page.

I keep getting errors about Promises, I feel there is a better way to do this?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const post = 
        axios.post(//api post request here)
            .then(function(response) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
            })

    const LoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;

    const logic = () => {
        if (LoggedIn) {
            //log user in
        } else {
            //redirect user to another page
        }
    };

    this.getValidToken()
        .then(post)
        .then(logic);

   //getValidToken firstly gets a cookie value which is then a payload for the post function
}

render() {
    return <Spinner />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you assign axios post to a variable, it is executed immediately and not after the getValidToken promise is resoved

Secondly the state update in react is async so you cannot have loggedIn logic based on state in promise resolver

You could handle the above scenario something like

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const post = () => axios.post(//api post request here)
            .then(function(response) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
                return true;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
                return false;
            })

    const logic = (isLoggedIn) => { // use promise chaining here
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            //log user in
        } else {
            //redirect user to another page
        }
    };

    this.getValidToken()
        .then(post)
        .then(logic);

   //getValidToken firstly gets a cookie value which is then a payload for the post function
}

render() {
    return <Spinner />;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh fantastic, thank you @Shubham, am trying the changes now, make so much sense now!